# BASH find file names but skip a list of file names

Tags: bash, printf, sh, filenames

I'm trying to set up a process in BASH from the "find" output. However I also have a list of file names that should not be process but they are in the same directory. I can't differentiate the files by file type.

An example is the following:

```
m001.png
m002.jpg
m003.tif
m004.png
m005.svg
...
m300.png
```

Let's say I have a list with the names I do not want to process:

```
m003.tif
m005.svg
m055.tif
m056.png
m078.jpg
m079.jpg
...
m275.svg
```

The list seems random in types but finite and I can't separate the files by type, i.e.

```
find . ! -name '\*.svg' ! -name '\*.tif' -exec sh c <process> {} +
```

is not an option.

Is there a way to combine find and printf in order to recursively create a find command?

Comment: why not have your `c` script check if the file should be skipped or not? it'd be just a couple lines at the start of the script: "is the file specified on the command line listed in the do-not-touch file?".

Comment: Maybe the script that you execute after could check if the file is in the "don't process list" and skip it.

Comment: or `find .... | fgrep -vf $excludeFile | xargs c` ? Good luck.

Comment: A straightforward solution: move the files you don't want to process somewhere else, launch your script, and move the files back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about :

```
find . $(printf "! -name %s " $(cat exclude_list_file)) -exec process {} \;
```